# Uninstalling a file using command line. windows 10

Tags: windows

I am trying to uninstall a few things using my command line but i am running into this error message--> Unexpected switch at this level <--- i have tried removing white spaces but still nothing. 
Any ideas?

```
wmic:root\cli>product where name-"Epic Games Launcher Prerequisites (x64)" call uninstall
Unexpected switch at this level.
```

Comment: You've posted partial information and are expecting us to debug an issue with it. Please review [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your post to provide the entire command line you're running. (`name-` appears to be incorrect, BTW. Equality is not expressed using a hyphen. The first step in debugging is to carefully read your code or command.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was when trying to run the function it did not have a location to pull from. This is because between `PRODUCT WHERE NAME` and the requested program there needs to be an `=`.

Assign it first

```
wmic:root\cli>PRODUCT WHERE NAME="Epic Games Launcher Prerequisites (64)"
```

then

```
wmic:root\cli>PRODUCT WHERE NAME="Epic Games Launcher Prerequisites (x64)" call uninstall
```